# got error in server when send email ; fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Permission denied)

Tags: php, email, smtp, codeigniter-3

here full error message when i try register data with send email validation, I tried the email sending feature locally, and it works, but when I deployed it to the server, I encountered an error.

full error message :

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: admin/Login.php

Line Number: 72

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/html/application/controllers/admin/Login.php
Line: 72
Function: _error_handler

File: /var/www/html/application/controllers/admin/Login.php
Line: 328
Function: sendEmail

File: /var/www/html/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Permission denied)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2069

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/html/application/controllers/admin/Login.php
Line: 79
Function: send

File: /var/www/html/application/controllers/admin/Login.php
Line: 328
Function: sendEmail

File: /var/www/html/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

**Note** : I use **Codeigniter 3**.

here my config to send Email, smtp.php :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // host gmail
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'myemailusingGmail@gmail.com'; // i am using gmail
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'my_pass_app';
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['smtp_debug'] = 2;
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
```

any solution?

Comment: Make sure the "allow_url_fopen" option is turned on in php.ini . This allows php to access remote urls as files.

Check below link for details  

https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen